# How can I run tar -xzf in Android

Tags: android, tar

I want my app to download a tar.tgz file and after extracts this in the package of application:

> /data/data/package

The download completed successfully, but I can't extract the tar file. I use the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask for downloading the tar file and the PostExecute() method to extract this. My code is:

```
class InstallPython extends AsyncTask< String, String, String > 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground( String... f_url )
        {
            int count = 0;
            byte data[] = new byte[ 15317957 ];

            try
            {
                //Create the URL object url for the Python binary URL.
                URL url = new URL( f_url[ 0 ] );

                //Create the URLConnection object connection for the previous URL object.
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                //Create the InputStream object input for reading from url object.
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( url.openStream(), 15317957 ); 

                //Create the OutputStream object output for writing.
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( "/data/data/com.rg.rgnettools/python.tar.tgz" );

                //Read from url object and write in the new file.
                while ( ( count = input.read( data ) ) != -1 )
                {                    
                    output.write( data, 0, count );
                }

                //Close file descriptors.
                output.flush(); 
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } 
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Log.e( "Download-Python-Error: ", e.getMessage() );
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute( String file_url )
        {
            try 
            {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{ "su", "-c", "tar -xzf /data/data/com.rg.rgnettools/python.tar.tgz" } );                
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Log.e( "SPLASHSCREENACTIVITY_ERROR", e.getMessage() );
            }           

        }
    }
```

Comment: your phone have rooted ?

Comment: you should specify a folder path where extracted data will be store. and you can post error log too.

Comment: I haven't errors ...

Comment: ok. you can try [cd] command to  /data/data/com.rg.rgnettools/ and [ls] file list inside to check su and your command is running ok

Comment: Yes, when I have executed tar -xzf from android terminal, the command executed successfully, but no from java code...

Comment: why have "-c" in your command set, only need {"su", "tar ...."} ?